# Help with changing style of the extended menu drop down

Tags: menus, css

I am trying to change the style of the extended menu drop down from being on the right side to the left side. As you can see by the picture provided, the menu item named "Catholic Women's league of Canada" comes down on the right side. The reason why I want to change it to the left side is because under my "Contact" menu item there are two sub items similar to the "Parish Committees" menu item and the menu travels off of the screen. Any ideas of where I can look in the style.css file to find where I can change the way these menu items drop down?

[image: Menu item display]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be something like this in the CSS:

```
.menu ul ul ul {
  left: XXpx;
}
```

Try changing that to

```
.menu ul ul ul {
  right: XXpx;
}
```

But nothing can be said for sure without seeing the CSS first.